# Is this possible to install SFDX CLI on Heroku instance?

Tags: salesforcedx, salesforcedx-cli, heroku, force-cli

I am trying to follow commands to install SFDX CLI on Heroku instance.

When I execute commands

```
>heroku run bash
>wget https://developer.salesforce.com/media/salesforce-cli/sfdx-linux-amd64.tar.xz
```

I receive an error:

> bash: wget: command not found

When I then try to run install command to install wget,

```
>sudo apt-get install wget
```

I receive an error

> bash: sudo: command not found

When I execute just

```
>apt-get install wget
```

I receive errors

> W: Not using locking for read only lock file /var/lib/dpkg/lock
>
> E: Unable to write to /var/cache/apt/
>
> E: The package lists or status file could not be parsed or opened.

Ok, there should be a way to install sfdx without root access provided Node.js is installed. On heroku instance with Node.js it is installed

```
$ node --version
```

> v0.4.7

However, `npm` command to install sfdx, is not available

```
npm install sfdx-cli --global
```

> bash: npm: command not found

Did anyone managed to resolve this issue?

Is this possible to install SFDX CLI on Heroku instance at all?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yes, the DX CLI can run on Heroku.
Wade Wegner contributed this buildpack here:
https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-cli-buildpack

**EDITED:** added some extra details on how to install it since the readme is minimalist and outdated:

1) create the Heroku app

```
heroku create
```

2) Set the buildpack

```
heroku buildpacks:set https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-cli-buildpack
```

3) Push sources (you should see that the salesforce-cli-buildpack is detected)

```
git push heroku master
```

4) Run bash (notice that the Salesforce CLI is added to path automatically)

```
heroku run bash
```

5) Check that it works

```
sfdx -v
```

6) Enjoy your favorite Salesforce DX commands :)

Comment: Did I understand you correctly, if I run "heroku create node-mine -b https://github.com/heroku/salesforce-cli-buildpack" then I will get an app with sfdx preinstalled, but when I run this command followed by "heroku run bash" and "sfdx" I receive "bash: sfdx: command not found", or did I misunderstand you?

Comment: Did you export the command paths as indicated in the readme?

Comment: I have executed both commands in commands line but that didn't work. Did I understand correctly that those two commands I was supposed to execute after heroku run bash?

Comment: I just retried the full install and it looks like the readme is outdated, the SFDX command is already included in the path so you don't need to add it yourself.

Comment: See edited answer for detailed instructions.